Gatling 3.x managing SSL switch in the same scenario
I am currently working on a performance test using gatling https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.gatling/gatling-app/3.9.5
Now my scenario includes, calls that will not require mtls at first and others that will requires mtls. Setting the ssl in the gatling.conf, will result in applying the keystore to all the calls.
I would like to manage both calls in the same scenario.
ChainBuilder mychain =
            exec(
                    http("First call without mtls")
                    .get("url_non_mtls"))
                    .queryParam("xxx", "xxxx")
                    .queryParam("xxx", "xxxx")
                    .check(status().is(302))
                    .exec(http("Second call with mtls")
                            .get("url_with_mtls")
                            .ignoreProtocolHeaders()
                            .header("accept", "application/json")
                            .header("x-request-id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())


I would appreciate any suggestion
A possible strategy to manage both calls
